# Scapy - srp1 does not see the response frame on L2, but tcpdump see it just fine

Tags: layer, scapy, tcpdump

sending the scapy packet as below over eth3

```
ans, unans = srp1(REQUEST, iface=self.iface)
print ans, unans
```

the call never returns, I tried srp too. (send/sendp/sniff too). I see response as None or call just hangs.

However, I could see the request and response on tcpdump just fine

```
listening on eth3, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
16:52:52.565683 00:26:55:27:1c:a2 (oui Unknown) > Broadcast, ethertype Unknown (0x88f8), length 34:
    0x0000:  ffff ffff ffff 0026 5527 1ca2 88f8 0001
    0x0010:  000b 1500 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 ffff
    0x0020:  eaf4
16:52:52.576476 00:04:25:1c:a0:02 (oui Unknown) > Broadcast, ethertype Unknown (0x88f8), length 76:
    0x0000:  ffff ffff ffff 0004 251c a002 88f8 0001
    0x0010:  000b 9500 0028 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
    0x0020:  0000 f1f0 f100 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
    0x0030:  0000 0000 0000 0803 0087 1634 XXXX XXXX
    0x0040:  XXXX 0000 XXXX XXXX XXXX ffff
```

Comment: Can you include the code for the request you are sending?

Comment: What exactly are you looking for ? REQUEST is a Packet chunk. I tried a C utility to send the bytes and it goes fine on the interface (eth1).

Comment: I am having the same problem with custom L2 protocol. The problem is that send-n-receive does not recognize answer packet (containing payload different than in request).

I am not sure how to associate answer packet layer

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out and sharing it -

If you define new protocol with custom payloads, Answer layer should implement "answers" method:

e.g:

```
class MyAnswer(Packet):
    name = "MyAnswer"
    fields_desc = [ByteEnumField("isOk", 0. BooleanFields)]

    def answers(self, other):
         return isinstance(other, MyRequest)
```